# Does three.js renderer clone the objects positions?

Tags: javascript, three.js, renderer

I created a small scene with 3 spheres and a triangle connecting the 3 centers of the spheres, i.e. the triangle vertex positions are the same variables as the sphere positions.
Now I expected that if i change the position of one of the spheres, the triangle vertex should be moved together with it (since it's the same position object) and therefore still connect the three spheres.
However, if I do this coordinate change AFTER the renderer was called, the triangle is NOT changed. (Though it does change if I move the sphere BEFORE the renderer is called.)
This seems to indicate that the renderer doesnt use the original position objects but a clone of them.

Q: Is there a way to avoid this cloning behaviour (or whatever is the reason for the independent positions) so I can still change two objects with one variable change? Or am I doing something wrong?

The code:

```
var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
renderer.setSize(width, height);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
var scene = new THREE.Scene;

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(30, width / height, 0.1, 10000);
camera.position=new THREE.Vector3(50,50,50);
camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));
scene.add(camera);

var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
pointLight.position=camera.position;
scene.add(pointLight);

var sphere=[];
var sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1,8,8);
var sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 });
var triGeom = new THREE.Geometry();
for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
    sphere[i] = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, sphereMaterial);
    sphere[i].position=new THREE.Vector3(10*i,20+5*(i-1)^2,0);
    scene.add(sphere[i]);
    triGeom.vertices.push(sphere[i].position);
}
triGeom.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 0, 1, 2 ) );
triGeom.computeFaceNormals();
var tri= new THREE.Mesh( triGeom, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({side:THREE.DoubleSide, color: 0x00ff00}) );
scene.add(tri);

sphere[0].position.x+=10; // this changes both sphere and triangle vertex
renderer.render(scene, camera);
sphere[1].position.x+=10; // this changes only the sphere
renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because of geometry caching feature. You will have to set **triGeom.verticesNeedUpdate = true** every time you change vertex position.